# rsync port 22 and 873 use

Tags: ssh, rsync, daemon

Can someone explain when does `rsync` use port 22 on the remote host and when does it use port 873?

Can it be set to always port 22, since I heard it has to use port 873 if it is run as a daemon? Can someone explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For context, the `rsync` documentation says

> There are two different ways for rsync to contact a remote system: using a remote-shell  program  as  the
>          transport  (such  as ssh or rsh) or contacting an rsync daemon directly via TCP.  The remote-shell transport is used whenever the source or destination path contains a single colon (:) separator after  a  host
>          specification.   Contacting an rsync daemon directly happens when the source or destination path contains
>          a double colon (::) separator after a host specification, OR when an rsync:// URL is specified.

Port 22 is the SSH port; it’s used when you tell `rsync` to connect *via* SSH, with a single colon (the “remote-shell” case above). Port 873 is the `rsync` dæmon port; it’s used when `rsync` is used with a double colon or a `rsync://` URL.

Most of the time you’ll be using SSH; using the dæmon requires specific setup. If you only ever want to use port 22, all you need to do is always specify a single colon in the remote host descriptor.

Comment: will communication on port 873 be encrypted as SSH is? If not is there a possibility that this is configured to be encrypted?

Comment: No, communications with `rsyncd` on port 873 aren’t encrypted unless you use an encrypting transport (such as SSH, in which case it uses port 22). `rsync` deals with this transparently if you use a path containing a single colon.

Answer (score 22):

You can use parameter -e to specify the ssh port, e.g.
rsync -rvz -e 'ssh -p $port'  ./dir user@host:/path